# Firebase / Node.js, correct usage of on.Disconnect()

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a node.js, the monitors a queue on Firebase, to send GCM Push notifications. Works fine.

It also updates an "online" status on firebase via `.onDisconnect()`, so one can easily see if the Node.js server is online and running.

Problem: after some time it will show "disconnected" even when the listener is still connected and running fine.

```
const NODESERVERONLINE="NodeSeverStatus";
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+FBKEY_GCM_QUEUE);
ref.child("NODESERVERONLINE").set("Online");
ref.child("NODESERVERONLINE").onDisconnect().set("Offline!");

ref.on("child_added",function(snapshot, prevChild){
    If (snapshot.key()!=NODESERVERONLINE) DO_GCM_PUSH(snapshot.val());
  }, function(errorObject){
    console.log("Error reading Firebase: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Initially, the listener is running and -NodeSeverStatus shows Online.

However "after some time" (several hours), the listener is still running fine, and the queue is being processed, but NodeServerStatus now shows Offline.

I could move the online/offline code inside the listener itself, but that would appear to just be an ugly hack, and would presumably still have the same issue if there were no new queue posts within the timeout period.

What is best practice here? Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick guess is that your network connection gets interrupted briefly.

If you network connection flaps, the server will detect the disconnect and set `Offline!`.

The client will automatically reconnect, but you never set `Online` again.

So you'll want to listen for `.info/connected` and set `Online` there.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
ref.child("NODESERVERONLINE").onDisconnect().set("Offline!");
ref.child(".info/connected").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() === true) {
    ref.child("NODESERVERONLINE").set("Online");
  }
});
```

See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html